# Setting position of a application in windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a programm, which calls an extern application. The application is designed to run with 2 monitors. The first programm on monitor 1 and the second at monitor 2.

Now i have the problem that the extern application has no parameter I can give them to enforce raising on the second monitor.

Is there any possability to force another application to chance his position. Also good would be a possability to enforce changing his window state (always start as maximized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this instruction from MSDN.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162827(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162827%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Functions from WinAPI you'll need are

`FindWindow` - Find the window handle (`HWND`)

`SetWindowPos` - Sets the window position

`ShowWindow` - Change window state

`EnumDisplayMonitors` - Get monitor information

See pinvoke.net how to import these functions in C#

Comment: Thank you verry much for the keywords. Thats all i need to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

API can help you achieve same

so start by declaring

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    const int SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3;
    const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
```

to use above simply invoke the target app and send it where you want it to and maximize

```
    Process p = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("notepad"));
    Thread.Sleep(1000); //depends
    IntPtr handle = p.MainWindowHandle;
    SetWindowPos(handle, IntPtr.Zero, 200, 200, 500, 600, SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    ShowWindowAsync(handle, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
```

above example is using notepad, you will choose your app here